# Two nodes in a custom control jar files

Tags: custom-controls, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have customized a text field as a number spinner which includes three files

1. NumberSpinner.java - extends HBox
2. NumberTextfield.java - extends TextField
3. Demo.java - extend Application

when I am running the application I got the desired result but when the application is imported in Scene Builder as jar it is not running as desired its showing me to include two files i.e. NumberSpinner and NumberTextfield both. when I am including the number spinner its not the same which I have customized so the question is, is it possible to have two nodes in a same application ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your custom components jar first

[image]

And than you will be able to use your custom component

[image]